# No text received when attempting to reactivate an expired Azure account trial

Tags: azure, authentication, sms, activation-codes

I have created a trial account which has now expired and got automatically disabled.  When I attempt to upgrade my subscription I'm stuck at the login screen.  I get told that my account is locked and have the option to click "Next".  I'm asked to input my phone number to receive a security code via text (SMS) - it's the only option available, no option to get a call instead.

However, no matter how much I tried, even with different phones, I never received a text.  Now it seems I have used all the possible attempts and I'm told that "Usage limit exceeded. Try again tomorrow."  I can't seem to find a way to contact anyone since support is offered AFTER you login, which is why I need help - not being able to login.  It seems that Microsoft's SMS gateway doesn't work that well in my country (MT).

My subscription ID is 78d9426f-d16d-4bf0-b3c9-394c9c70efc2.

Comment: I don't think you will find an answer to this problem here. Please reach out to Azure Support. They're quite active on Twitter (@AzureSupport).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question for Azure Support.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that.  Thanks